# Deploying WSP remotely from PowerShell 3.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting, wsp

I have this large application that I am using Windows RM 3.0 to deploy Databases, SSIS packages, and other things to multiple different servers and it is working just fine. It was requested that branding changes to a Business Intelligence SharePoint site be added to this process as well. So I create a custom build script to do so, and set Win RM to run this command from PowerShell on Sharepoint server

```
Install-SPSolution –Identity Payload\SharepointDeploy.wsp –WebApplication http://localhost/ -GACDeployment
```

when I run that, I get the following error

> Install-SPSolution : Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version 4.0.30319.18444 of the Microsoft .Net Runtime.

Reading around, it seems its a PowerShell 3.0 issue and when running in 2.0 it works fine. However, my existing process requires PowerShell 3.0 to work properly. Is there anyway to get this working with 3.0? Or can I spin up a 2.0 instance using an Invoke-Command or something? I can provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a custom endpoint which will run the required version of PowerShell. That way you won't have to mess with the default endpoint which you probably want to keep with its defaults

This would require you to connect to the new endpoint with something like
new-pssession -computername "SharePoint01" -configurationName "psv2".

You build and endpoint with the following cmdlet:

```
New-PSSessionConfigurationFile -Path "psv2session.pssc"
```

And then register an endpoint using that config with this cmdlet:

```
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name psv2 -Path psv2session.pssc –ShowSecurityDescriptorUI
```

It's fairly easy to do, and this link provides a good introduction to the setup:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/04/02/build-constrained-powershell-endpoint-using-configuration-file.aspx (although the blog deals with constrained endpoints, the teqnique is essentially the same for what you need to do)

Comment: Thanks, I must be doing something wrong. I added the new session config file, but get the same error message when I run the install command. Is there a step I could have missed?

Comment: Hard to say. What does $psversiontable tell you inside a session on the new endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with console application, I decreased the framework version from 4.5 to 3.5 from the project properties page and I works perfect!